# EF5 generating "imaginary" columns in select statements

Tags: c#, join, entity-framework-5

We are using C#. VS2012, EF 5.0, and Oracle 11g.  Approach is code first.  I have a table that is defined, and it is plainly visible in looking at the code that it is defined with all the correct columns (and none that are not there.)

Still, when I run certain LINQ queries (joins) and attempt to select the results into a new object, things break.  Here is the LINQ:

```
IQueryable<CheckWage> query =
    from clientWage in context.ClientWages
    join paycheckWage in context.PaycheckWages
        on
        new {clientWage.PermanentClientId, clientWage.WageId} equals
        new {paycheckWage.PermanentClientId, paycheckWage.WageId}
    where
        (paycheckWage.PermanentClientId == Session.PermanentClientId) &&
        (clientWage.PermanentClientId == Session.PermanentClientId)
    select new CheckWage
        {
            CWage = clientWage,
            PWage = paycheckWage
        };
```

Now, here is the SQL it emits (as captured by Devart's DbMonitor tool):

```
SELECT 
"Extent1".ASSOCIATE_NO,
"Extent1".PCLIENT_ID,
"Extent1".CLIENT_NO,
"Extent1".CLIENT_NAME,
"Extent1".ADDRESS1,
"Extent1".ADDRESS2,
"Extent1".CITY,
"Extent1".STATE,
"Extent1".ZIP,
"Extent1".COUNTRY,
"Extent1".CLIENT_TYPE,
"Extent1".DOING_BUSINESS_AS,
"Extent1".CONTACT,
"Extent1".PHONE,
"Extent1".EXTENSION,
"Extent1".FAX,
"Extent1".FAX_EXTENSION,
"Extent1".EMAIL,
"Extent1".NEXTEMP,
"Extent1".PAY_FREQ,
"Extent1".EMPSORT,
"Extent1".DIVUSE,
"Extent1".CLIENT_ACCESS_TYPE,
"Extent1".AUTOPAY_WAGE_ID,
"Extent1".FEIN,
"Extent1".HR_MODULE,
"Extent1".BANK_CODE,
"Extent1".ACH_DAYS,
"Extent1".ACH_COLLECT,
"Extent1".UPDATED,
"Extent1".IAT_FLAG,
"Extent1".ORIG_EMAIL,
"Extent1"."R1",
"Extent1"."R2"
FROM INSTANTPAY.CLIENT "Extent1"
WHERE "Extent1".PCLIENT_ID = :EntityKeyValue1'
```

There are no such columns as "R1" and "R2."  I am guessing is has something to do with the join into a new object type with two properties, but I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out what I've done or haven't done that is resulting in this errant SQL.  Naturally, the error from the Oracle server is "ORA-00904: "Extent1"."R2": invalid identifier."  Strange that is doesn't choke on R1, but perhaps it only lists the last error or something...

Thanks in advance,
Peter

**5/23/2014: I left out an important detail.  The SQL is emitted when I attempt to drill into one of the CheckWage objects (using Lazy loading), as both of the contained objects have a navigation property to the "Client" entity.  I can access the client table just fine in other LINQ queries that do not use a join, it is only this one that creates the "R1" and "R2" in the SELECT statement.**

Peter

Comment: Is this the only query that's executed? I don't understand why the join doesn't show. This looks like a query triggered by lazy loading (of course it should still be correct).

Comment: You are right about the lazy loading - in the code after the query, I attempt to drill into one of the CheckWage objects, and both objects inside THAT object have a navigation property to the "Client" entity.  The Client table is defined correctly as far as I can see, and I can access it with no problem with other LINQ statements as long as I don't do a join.

Comment: I am facing this same problem with EF 6.1

Comment: We had the same problem. An entity was updated because a foreign key was removed, but we forgot to update the related entity. When we removed the same foreign key in the related entity, it worked.